# Installing gettext in virtual environment of shared hosting

Tags: django, cpanel, multilingual, gettext

I made a multilingual django website and I am deploying it to shared hosting. I should install gettext to virtual environment. I have read about gettext is not python package so I can't install it using pip.

Is there any way to install gettext in virtual environment of shared hosting?

I can't use sudo because I don't have root access.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [GNU gettext](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/) inside your home directory. Build it like this:

1. configure --prefix=~/path/where/to/install
2. make
3. make install

You don't need root access for that but the usual build tools like a C compiler.

Alternatively, build a static version of gettext, and copy all tools somewhere under your home diretory.

In any case, you have to add the location of the binaries to your `$PATH`.